# Ajax or not : which is harder/longer to code using zend framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I'm planning to create an ajax based web application using zend framework..
will i have a hard time coding it when it's ajax based or not?

Comment: You should ask yourself if you **need** ajax. If you do, use it. In software development questions like yours shouldn't exist.

Comment: I think you should give it a shot. Play with the new HTML5 Api pushstate. Or you could use hash based URLs when page loads, load the ajax content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining AJAX and Zend Framework should not be a problem. Have a look at

http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/10/26/handling-ajax-requests-in-the-zend-framework

or

http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/04/17/5-things-working-with-zend-framework-and-ajax/

to get an idea of how to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

Coding with ajax or not should not be a issue its your necessity if you need it you use it if you dont need it you dont use it that's simple. And regarding will it be hard or not it totally depends on how you are with ajax and zend, integration of two should not be an issue in most of the case I believe.